# Using Certificate for authentication WITHOUT HttpContext

Tags: 2013, csom, certificate

I created a provider hosted app for SharePoint 2013(OnPrem) which works with the standard "Tokenhelper.cs" to connect to SharePoint.

I use a certificate for authorization which works fine on my app.

Now I also have a TimerJob on the same machine, that needs to communicate with SharePoint. In my TimerJob I do not have any httpContext obviously, which is needed to use the following code:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);
using (var appContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost()) {}
var web=appContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can connect using credentials instead:

```
var appContext= new ClientContext(siteUri);
appContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var web=appContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I do not want to use any credentials but pure Certificate authentication instead. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below method from TokenHelper:

```
var SPHostUrl = new Uri("http://your_sp_farm/sites/your_site");
var accessToken = TokenHelper.GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity(SPHostUrl, null);
using(var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(SPHostUrl.AbsoluteUri, accessToken)){...}
```

You also need to create `app.config` for you job (I'm assuming that's console app) and put into the same appSettings as for normal web application (`ClientSigningCertificatePath`, etc.)